# How can I log into Imdb pro Page Using Java?

Tags: java, jsoup, imdb

I want to take some metadata using my imdb pro account.

The page that I'm going to look for is this:

```
https://pro-labs.imdb.com/title/{IMDB ID}
```

I try to open the link with Jsoup, but it returns the following error:

> java.io.IOException: 403 error loading URL
>   http://pro.imdb.com/signup/v4/login?u=https://pro-labs.imdb.com/title/{IMDB
>   ID}.

This is because I am not logged.

This is the login page:   https://secure.imdb.com/signup/v4/login.

How can I make a request to include my log in info?

Comment: Have you tried HtmlUnit? It should work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is has only a limited support of login / authentication. Better you use another library (recommendation: *Apache HttpClient*) to do this.

In general you then can do these steps:

1. **Login** using eg. HttpClient
2. **Download** the websitde into a buffer
3. **Parse** this buffer using jsoup
4. **Process** the content as required